# Moving ec2 instance with SSL

Tags: linux, ssl, amazon-ec2, server

I have a EC2 instance that I have to reset the sudo.

Created a new Instance, if I just detach everything from old instance and attach to new instance again, what will happen to the ssl cert that was on the old system? is that included in the volume?

Comment: what you mean by 'reset the sudo'?

Comment: @Putnik Some post said to use R chom 755 on var/www/ .. to fix permission issue in ftp which destroyed all access to the server.. right now I am trying to salvage this back to a working state

Comment: So, you need sudo or root access. If you don't have then create a new server won't work unless you move the site to the new server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 'detach everything' means EBS volumes then consider it as you take HHD from one server and put to another, hardware-compatible. So, all passwords etc will be the same.

The server will have another IP unless you took care about it, it may have different subnet if you selected it during creation, but all the rest is the same.